# Is there a way to use Rails.application.credentials in a ruby non rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to access the encrypted credentials of a rails project from another ruby project (actually it's a AWS lambda) which should share the same models and database. The database connection string is encrypted inside the rails credentials file.

Is there a way for a non rails ruby project to access the encrypted credentials data given it has access to the master.key file?

Answer (score 2):

Solved myself looking at ruby/ruby repo in github.
You need to import ActiveSupport.
In ruby you just:

```
require 'active_support/encrypted_configuration'
```

Then

```
credentials = ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration.new(config_path: <path/to/credentials.yml.enc>, key_path: <path/to/master.key>, env_key: <YOUR_RAILS_MASTER_KEY>, raise_if_missing_key: true)
```

You can now dig the file as it was a loaded YAML file.